# How to integrate FormValidation's external plugins with Metronic?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wizard, metronic, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

I'm working on a Wizard Form using the Metronic framework.
Metronic includes the FormValidation library, and states so in [their website](https://preview.keenthemes.com/html/metronic/docs/forms/formvalidation/overview)

In my project I can find the file in \assets\plugins\global\plugins.bundle.js

However, FormValidation has two groups of plugins: Core and External, as you can see [here](https://formvalidation.io/guide/plugins/).
I think Metronic only includes the Core ones, and I need to include an External one as well, namely, the Wizard one.

How can I do this?

In the Metronic site it's stated that they are already included, and in the FormValidation site they refer to a directory structure that's different than the one I have.

Is there a way to include FV's External Plugins to Metronic?

Right now I'm getting "FormValidation.plugins.Wizard is not a constructor" as an error in the console.

Thank You